# How do you explain this proof?

Tags: affine-geometry

I have this theorem with proof that i need to understand, however the proof in the book i am into is not complete.

Thm:
If $(p_1, p_2)$, $(q_1, q_2)$ and $(r_1, r_2)$ are vertices of a triangle, then the area of that triangle is the absolute value of    $\frac{1}{2}[(q_1-p_1)(r_2-p_2) - (q_2-p_2)(r_1-p_1)]$.

The proof in the book says that the first shaded triangle should be proven first and it is left for the reader. The first triangle(shaded) should be proven first

[image]

Then the following is given for the proof of the second triangle,which is the goal of the proof:
Since $τP,O(P)=(0,0)$, $τP,O(Q)=(a,b)$ and $τP,O(P)=(c,d)$, then the area of $∆PQR$ is also $\frac{1}{2}|ad-bc|$. Substitution then yields the expression given in the statement of the theorem.

However the only idea I have is that the translation that takes $P$ to $Q$ and $P$ to $R$ has equations: 
$q_1-p_1=a$ , $q_2-p_2=b$ and $r_1-p_1=c$ , $r_2-p_2=d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are simply relation between cartesian coordinates, for example with reference to PQ for the triangle on the right we have that

- distance $PQ$ in $x$ direction $= q_1-p_1$
- distance $PQ$ in $y$ direction $= q_2-p_2$

Since the shaded triangle is obtained by a translation of the right triangle such that $P\equiv O$, for the shaded triangle we have

- distance $PQ$ in $x$ direction $a= q_1-p_1$
- distance $PQ$ in $y$ direction $b = q_2-p_2$

and ths the point $Q$ for the shaded triangle has coordinates $(a,b)$.

Comment: how do you obtain that absolute value of 1/2[(q1−p1)(r2−p2)−(q2−p2)(r1−p1)

Comment: thanks, i got it, the proof just coonverted the triangle into a matrix and solved for the area which is 1/2|ad-bc|

Comment: Well done, You are welcome! Bye